# Create custom function to add/remove elements in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a custom function for adding/removing elements in arrays in Java. So I made something like this.

```
public class Arrays {
    static final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 10;
    int element;
    int[] add_Element(int array[], int index, int new_element)
    {
        int new_array[] = new int[array.length+1];
        int amount_of_elements = array.length;

        if(index > amount_of_elements)
        {
            System.out.printf("Choose new index\n");
        }
        else if(amount_of_elements == MAX_ELEMENTS)
        {
            System.out.println(amount_of_elements);
            System.out.printf("The array is full\n");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                new_array[i] = array[i];
            }
            for(int i = amount_of_elements - 1; i >= index; i--)
            {
                new_array[i + 1] = array[i];
            }
            new_array[index] = new_element;
            System.out.printf("The element is added.\n");
        }
        return new_array;
    }

    int[] remove_Element(int array[], int element)
    {
        int[] new_array = new int[array.length - 1];
        int amount_of_elements = array.length;
        boolean found = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < amount_of_elements; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] == element)
            {
                for(int j = i; j < amount_of_elements -1; j++)
                {
                    new_array[j] = array[j + 1];
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    new_array[j] = array[j];
                }
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(found == true)
        {
            System.out.printf("The element is removed.\n");
        }
        return new_array;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering, is there any 'easier' way to do this? Without all these checks, and loops? Preferably without using any external libraries or anything like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ?

Comment: You can use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) to copy chunks of the array.

Comment: There is actually already a class called Arrays that provides the functionality you require. Search for Arrays.copyOf(...). Further, your code would have a horribly bad performance because it would move all of the array elements each time one element is added or removed. ArrayList already implements this, but provides some extra space so there is no need to copy the whole array every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. ArrayList looks like a really nice solution for this.